# What is the fastest way to photodissociate/bleach melanin - with lasers or LEDs - without heat?

Tags: light-emitting-diodes, laser-interaction

Melanin is the chemical that makes our skin dark. Melanin absorbs in very well in the UV, but when one does so, the solution/molecule gets very hot.

Is there a way to photodissociate melanin without heating it, for example with some pulsed lasers, or some pulsed LEDs? Maybe a combination of two different wavelengths can do the trick?

Comment: Do you want to break down melanin directly inside the skin of a living human?  Or do you have a sample of  pure melanin on a surface?

Comment: I am thinking of a sample above all, but I would also be interested in the skin situation.